# Monitoring ZFS-FUSE

Tags: linux, debian, zfs, zfs-fuse

I am setting up a Debian-based host with a bunch of KVM-based virtual machines. Images of these VMs reside on a ZFS volume (I use ZFS-FUSE 0.6.9). Performance results seem to be very different from my another system, based on CentOS 6. I am concerned that Debian implementation of ZFS-FUSE ignores settings from `/etc/zfs/zfsrc`. How can I monitor actual state of ZFS-FUSE, say, ARC cache usage, vdev caches usage, etc?

Comment: Does [this](http://wiki.freebsd.org/ZFSTuningGuide) help?

Comment: @quanta No, because ZFS is implemented in kernel on FreeBSD, I do not have such parameters in Linux

Comment: Interesting question, I'm not sure how to check that on zfs-fuse. An alternate way to configure it on Debian is to set DAEMON_OPTS in /etc/default/zfs-fuse.

Comment: I suspect this doesn't help much, but Debian now has kFreeBSD kernel as an alternative to Linux kernel.

Comment: Are both systems similar (memory/disk)? Are you using different features (compression/deduplication)? You can also try compiling it from source, see http://zfs-fuse.net/ and the alternative repositories it mentions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ZFS-Fuse normally mounts the kstat filesystem on /zfs-kstat, see [this announcement](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/zfs-fuse/s7nx6XoKHw0/discussion). With it, you should be able to access all kstat values (mounting it [can fail](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/zfs-fuse/BWFm9f2wcFw/discussion) though).

You can monitor ARC usage and some interesting stats through [the arcstat.pl script](http://rainemu.swishparty.co.uk/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=zfs;a=blob;f=contrib/arcstat.pl;h=c8554d0644d50742e32047266f86e4b194191eb6;hb=3c80f0164d610989baf4d388a0835f3b163a2ffb).